# Intersecting lines with a circle after polar coordinates conversion

Tags: r, spatial, r-sf, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

I have a dataset in polar coordinates.
The dataset contains the coordinates of points that I cast in lines.
Then I want to intersect these lines with a circle. From the polar coordinates, you can see that the Boundary of the line is always 18 (which is also the limit of the circle).
In order to do the intersect I convert Polar coordinates to cartesian.
In the end, only some of the lines correctly intersect the circle, and I do not know why.
What works for me is a Not So Elegant Solution: I reduce the circle radius from 18 to 17.999. This works and I suppose that it is because the conversion from polar to cartesian is not 100%. For my purpose, the solution I found is enough, but I want to report it here (I do not know if this is a bug or I made some mistake),

[image: Split with circle of 18]

[image: Split with circle of 17.999]

Here is the reproducible example (with plots):

```
#My Dataset
Boundaries<- data.frame(UE = c(127,127,128,128,128,129,129,129,129,129),
                    ID_Line = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2), 
                    ID_Point = c(1,2,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2),
                    Azimut = c(10,120,120,90,230,120,90,230,90,270),
                    Distance = c(18,18,18,5,18,18,5,18,5,18)
                    )

library(tidyverse)
library(useful)

#Polar to Cartesian coordinates conversion
Boundariesxy<-as_tibble(Boundaries) %>%
  mutate(Theta = 2*pi*Azimut/360,
         x = pol2cart(Distance, Theta, degrees=F)[["y"]],
         y = pol2cart(Distance, Theta, degrees=F)[["x"]])


library(sf)
#Conversion to sf object
Boundaries_sf <- st_as_sf(Boundariesxy,
                          coords = c('x', 'y')) %>%
  st_set_crs("102010")  %>%
  group_by(UE, ID_Line)  %>%
  summarise() %>%
  ungroup()

#Cast as Linestring
Bound_lines <- st_cast(Boundaries_sf, "LINESTRING")

#Preparing a circle polygon
Point<- data.frame(
  Plot = c("A"),
  x = c(0),
  y = c(0))
#We convert the center of the circle in a spatial object using a CRS in meters 
Point_sf <- st_as_sf(Point,
                     coords = c('x', 'y')) %>%
  st_set_crs("102010") %>%
  st_convex_hull()
#Buffer 
Circle_st_18<-st_buffer(Point_sf,18)
Circle_st_17999<-st_buffer(Point_sf,17.999)

library(lwgeom)
#For each UE I do an intersect Line->Circle
B127<-Bound_lines[which(Bound_lines$UE==127),]
plot(B127)
Split_127<-st_split(Circle_st_18,B127)
plot(Split_127)
Split_127_2<-st_split(Circle_st_17999,B127)
plot(Split_127_2)
Poly_127 <- (Split_127 %>% st_collection_extract(c("POLYGON")))
st_area(Poly_127)
B128<-Bound_lines[which(Bound_lines$UE==128),]
plot(B128)
Split_128<-st_split(Circle_st_18,B128)
plot(Split_128)
Split_128_2<-st_split(Circle_st_17999,B128)
plot(Split_128_2)
Poly_128 <- (Split_128 %>% st_collection_extract(c("POLYGON")))
st_area(Poly_128)
B129<-Bound_lines[which(Bound_lines$UE==129),]
plot(B129)
Split_129<-st_split(Circle_st_18,B129)
plot(Split_129)
Poly_129 <- (Split_129 %>% st_collection_extract(c("POLYGON")))
st_area(Poly_129)
Split_129_2<-st_split(Circle_st_17999,B129)
plot(Split_129_2)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are seeing that is unexpected. When you plot `B127`, you see the exact same geometry two times. When you intersect that geometry with the circle, even if it intersected the same geometry 100 times, it will still be shown once (because they would be on top of each other). As far as I see, the intersection of the 18 bounded circle plots the intersections for me just find...perhaps I don't fully understand your question.

Comment: The intersection should work with the 18 circle. In my case it does not work.

Comment: Your circle that's supposed to be less than 18—you have `Circle_st_117` made in your code, but you call for `Circle_st_17`. I assumed that was a typo. It's also set at a dim of 1, whereas you mentioned just under 18, so I changed the `1` to `17.9`—then both worked. Are you sure it's not the smaller circle that isn't working?

Comment: From the image above you can see the result of the script I obtain: The circle 18 is not intersected unless I reduce the size to 17.999, and yes I made a mistake in the script...I will correct